# OptaPlanner- TSPTW minimizing total time

Tags: optaplanner

I am using OptaPlanner to solve what is effectively the Traveling Salesman Problem with Time Windows (TSPTW). I have a working initial solution based on the OptaPlanner provided VRPTW example.

I am now trying to address my requirements that deviate from the standard TSPTW, which are:

1. I am trying to minimize the total time spent rather than the total distance traveled. Because of this, idle time counts against me.
2. In additional to the standard time windowed visits I also must support no-later-than (NLT) visits (i.e. don't visit after X time) and no-earlier-than (NET) visits (i.e don't visit before X time).

My current solution always sets the first visit's arrival time to that visit's start time. This has the following problems with respect to my requirements:

1. This can introduce unnecessary idle time that could be avoided if the visit was arrived at sometime later in its time window.
2. The behavior with NLT is problematic. If I define an NLT with the start time set to Long.MIN_VALUE (to represent that it is unbounded without resorting to nulls) then that is the time the NLT visit is arrived at (the same problem as #1). I tried addressing this by setting the start time to the NLT time. This resulted in arriving just in time for the NLT visit but overshooting the time windows of subsequent visits.

How should I address this/these problems? I suspect a solution will involve ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener but I don't know what that solution should look like.

In case it's relevant, I've pasted in my current scoring rules below. One thing to note is that "distance" is really travel time. Also, for domain reasons, I am encouraging NLT and NET arrival times to be close to the cutoff time (end time for NLT, start time for NET).

```
import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardsoftlong.HardSoftLongScoreHolder;

global HardSoftLongScoreHolder scoreHolder;

// Hard Constraints
rule "ArrivalAfterWindowEnd"
  when
    Visit(arrivalTime > maxStartTime, $arrivalTime : arrivalTime, $maxStartTime : maxStartTime)
  then
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, $maxStartTime - $arrivalTime);
end

// Soft Constraints
rule "MinimizeDistanceToPreviousEvent"
  when
    Visit(previousRouteEvent != null, $distanceFromPreviousRouteEvent : distanceFromPreviousRouteEvent)
  then
    scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, -$distanceFromPreviousRouteEvent);
end

rule "MinimizeDistanceFromLastEventToHome"
  when
    $visit : Visit(previousRouteEvent != null)
    not Visit(previousRouteEvent == $visit)
    $home : Home()
  then
    scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, -$visit.getDistanceTo($home));
end

rule "MinimizeIdle"
  when
    Visit(scheduleType != ScheduleType.NLT, arrivalTime < minStartTime, $minStartTime : minStartTime, $arrivalTime : arrivalTime)
  then
    scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, $arrivalTime - $minStartTime);
end

rule "PreferLatestNLT"
  when
    Visit(scheduleType == ScheduleType.NLT, arrivalTime < maxStartTime, $maxStartTime : maxStartTime, $arrivalTime : arrivalTime)
  then
    scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, $arrivalTime - $maxStartTime);
end

rule "PreferEarliestNET"
  when
    Visit(scheduleType == ScheduleType.NET, arrivalTime > minStartTime, $minStartTime : minStartTime, $arrivalTime : arrivalTime)
  then
    scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, $minStartTime - $arrivalTime);
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by modifying ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener's updateArrivalTime method to reach backwards and (attempt to) shift the previous arrival time. Additionally, I introduced a getPreferredStartTime() method to support NLT events defaulting to as late as possible. Finally, just for code cleanliness, I moved the updateArrivalTime method from ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener into the Visit class.

Here is the relevant code from the Visit class:

```
public long getPreferredStartTime()
{
    switch(scheduleType)
    {
        case NLT:
            return getMaxStartTime();
        default:
            return getMinStartTime();
    }
}

public Long getStartTime()
{
    Long arrivalTime = getArrivalTime();
    if (arrivalTime == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    switch(scheduleType)
    {
        case NLT:
            return arrivalTime;
        default:
            return Math.max(arrivalTime, getMinStartTime());
    }
}

public Long getEndTime()
{
    Long startTime = getStartTime();
    if (startTime == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return startTime + duration;
}

public void updateArrivalTime(ScoreDirector scoreDirector)
{
    if(previousRouteEvent instanceof Visit)
    {
        updateArrivalTime(scoreDirector, (Visit)previousRouteEvent);
        return;
    }

    long arrivalTime = getPreferredStartTime();
    if(Utilities.equal(this.arrivalTime, arrivalTime))
    {
        return;
    }

    setArrivalTime(scoreDirector, arrivalTime);
}

private void updateArrivalTime(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, Visit previousVisit)
{
    long departureTime = previousVisit.getEndTime();
    long arrivalTime = departureTime + getDistanceFromPreviousRouteEvent();

    if(Utilities.equal(this.arrivalTime, arrivalTime))
    {
        return;
    }

    if(arrivalTime > maxStartTime)
    {
        if(previousVisit.shiftTimeLeft(scoreDirector, arrivalTime - maxStartTime))
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    else if(arrivalTime < minStartTime)
    {
        if(previousVisit.shiftTimeRight(scoreDirector, minStartTime - arrivalTime))
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    setArrivalTime(scoreDirector, arrivalTime);
}

/**
 * Set the arrival time and propagate the change to any following entities.
 */
private void setArrivalTime(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, long arrivalTime)
{
    scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(this, "arrivalTime");
    this.arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
    scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(this, "arrivalTime");

    Visit nextEntity = getNextVisit();
    if(nextEntity != null)
    {
        nextEntity.updateArrivalTime(scoreDirector, this);
    }
}

/**
 * Attempt to shift the arrival time backward by the specified amount.
 * @param requested The amount of time that should be subtracted from the arrival time.
 * @return Returns true if the arrival time was changed.
 */
private boolean shiftTimeLeft(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, long requested)
{
    long available = arrivalTime - minStartTime;
    if(available <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    requested = Math.min(requested, available);
    if(previousRouteEvent instanceof Visit)
    {
        //Arrival time is inflexible as this is not the first event. Forward to previous event.
        return ((Visit)previousRouteEvent).shiftTimeLeft(scoreDirector, requested);
    }

    setArrivalTime(scoreDirector, arrivalTime - requested);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Attempt to shift the arrival time forward by the specified amount.
 * @param requested The amount of time that should be added to the arrival time.
 * @return Returns true if the arrival time was changed.
 */
private boolean shiftTimeRight(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, long requested)
{
    long available = maxStartTime - arrivalTime;
    if(available <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    requested = Math.min(requested, available);
    if(previousRouteEvent instanceof Visit)
    {
        //Arrival time is inflexible as this is not the first event. Forward to previous event.
        //Note, we could start later anyways but that won't decrease idle time, which is the purpose of shifting right
        return ((Visit)previousRouteEvent).shiftTimeRight(scoreDirector, requested);
    }

    setArrivalTime(scoreDirector, arrivalTime + requested);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To see an example that uses **real road times** instead of road distances: In the examples app, open Vehicle Routing, click button Import, load the file `roaddistance/capacitated/belgium-road-time-n50-k10.vrp`. Those times were [calculated with GraphHopper](https://github.com/ge0ffrey/vrp-dataset-generator/blob/master/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/extension/vrpdatasetgenerator/FromCsvLocationsToVrpGenerator.java).

To see an example that uses Time Windows, open the Vehicle Routing and quick open a dataset that is called `cvrptw` (tw stands for Time Windows). If you look at the academic spec (linked from docs chapter 3 IIRC) for CVRPTW, you'll see it already has a hard constraint "Do not arrive after time window closes" - so you'll see that one in score rules drl. As for arriving too early (and therefore losing the idle time): copy paste that hard constraint, make it a soft, make it use readyTime instead of dueTime and reverse it's comparison and penalty calculation. I actually originally implemented that (as it's the logical thing to have), but because I followed the academic spec (to compare with results of the academics) I had to remove it.

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey. I believe I have this soft constraint already, see the MinimizeIdle rule (I exclude NLT so as not to overlap PreferLatestNLT and double penalize). The additional soft constraint is part of the solution, but it doesn't address the first visit always starting at the beginning of the time window even if this unnecessarily introduces idle time.

Comment: put the time window start on the vehicle (or it's depot) then add a rule `when Customer.previousStandstill is vehicle and the Customer readyTime is higher than arrivalTime then ...`